# How to get Multi selected columns in the alert message using Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Have small requirement, need to select multiple cells randomly. Once we click on the button, we have to show the all selected cells data in one alert message.

I tried below code, can you please help for this, getting "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`" error

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
         $(this).toggleClass('selected'); 
    } );

    $('#button').click(function() {
        var cellData = table.cell('.selected').data();
        var consoleMsg = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < cellData.length; i++) {
            consoleMsg += cellData[i] + '\n';
        }
        alert(consoleMsg);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6vxgo1k/3/)

Comment: In `click(function() { ` do `console.log(cellData)` and see why it's null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly looking at your code, I don't see how you're expecting to get your dataTables data into `this` when `this` is your `$('#button')`.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
        var cellData = table.cell( this ).data(); // this = #button not your #table
        var consoleMsg = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < cellData.length; i++) {
            consoleMsg += cellData[i] + '\n';
        }
        alert(consoleMsg);
    });
```

What value do you expect `this` to be?

UPDATE:
Okay, so looking at your fiddle you need to change your code to this:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
        var cellData = table.cell($('.selected').data());
        //console.log(cellData);
        var consoleMsg = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < cellData.length; i++) {
            consoleMsg += cellData[i];
        }
        alert(consoleMsg);
    });
```

The problem is that you need to pass an object, but you were only passing text.

Comment: Trying to get the cells count using   var cellData = table.cell('.selected').data();

Comment: Ahh okay, try changing to this: `var cellData = table.cell($('.selected').data());` You need to actually pass the jQuery object in rather than just the text `.selected`

Comment: You'll actually need to do `$('.selected')[0].data()` or something similar as that's a class and not an id.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I updated my fix...now all fine.

Comment: Good to hear that!